# How to detect words starting with # in listings package?

Tags: listings, conditionals, characters

I am writing some code with the listings package and I need to detect the words starting with the number sign (`#`) and apply certain style. For example, if I have this code:

```
 something #foo anotherThing
```

I would like to put blue colors to '#foo'.

So far I have:

```
\lstset{
....
identifierstyle=\idstyle, 
}
```

And then:

```
 \makeatletter
 \newcommand*\idstyle{%
         \expandafter\id@style\the\lst@token\relax
 }
 \def\id@style#1#2\relax{%
         \ifcat#1\relax\else
                 \ifnum`#1=\uccode`#1%
                    \small\ttfamily\color{red!100!black}
                \fi
                 \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{\#}=0
         \small\ttfamily\color{blue!100!black}

         \fi
           \ifnum`#1= 35%
                         \small\ttfamily\color{blue!100!black}
                 \fi
         \fi
 }
 \makeatother
```

So I am trying to put a blue color for words starting with `#`. The first try (using `\pdfstrcmp`) works perfect with others type of characters but not with `#`. I cannot scape it. I tried to scape `#` in lots of ways such as `\#`, `\#\`, `|\verb#|`, etc et, but no one worked.

In the second try, I am trying to go by comparing the unicode value, but I am not successful either.

Notice also that at the same time I wanted to put colors (different color) to words that start with uppercase. So how can I have both at the same time (set different colors to both, words that start with uppercase and those that start with `\#`?

Sorry for the question but I am newbie with Latex...

Any ideas how can I get this?

Comment: I'm almost sure to read in the past a similar question in which they wanted to set with a certain style words preceded by `@`. Unfortunately I can't find it now :(

Comment: Hi Marco. Thanks for the welcome :)  As you can see in the question, I do use \# but still it does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will try to answer your question. The symbol `#` is a specific character, also within `listings`. To detect the symbol inside the identifier style you must declare `#` as a letter. By default it is declared as "other". Table 2: Standard character table of [the great documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) shows the default setting. So you can do the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{%
alsoletter=\#,
identifierstyle=\idstyle, 
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\idstyle[1]{%
         \expandafter\id@style\the\lst@token{#1}\relax%
 }
 \def\id@style#1#2\relax{%
           \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{\#}=0%
                \small\ttfamily\color{blue!100!black} \the\lst@token%
            \else%
              \edef\tempa{\uccode`#1}%
              \edef\tempb{`#1}%
              \ifnum\tempa=\tempb%
                  \small\ttfamily\color{red!100!black} \the\lst@token%
              \else%
                  \the\lst@token%
             \fi%
            \fi%
 }
 \makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
something #foo another Thing
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @MarianoMartinezPeck: Edit and please remove you last answer.

Comment: Wow. Thanks Marco. That works great. Thanks *A LOT*.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `keywordsprefix=\#` to specify that anything beginning with `#` is to be treated as a keyword:

[image]

### Notes:

- See restrictions associated with this documented at [Listings language definition keyword suffixes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44914/listings-language-definition-keyword-suffixes/45093#45093).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{%
    backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!20},%
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,%
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,%
    language=Java,%
    keywordsprefix=\#,%
    alsoletter=\#,%  if you also want the "#" to be highlighted
    }%

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
  something #foo anotherThing
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. However, that means that I would have to apply the same styles to those words starting with `#` and keywords. In my case I need both and both with different styles.