# Why does this simple \ifx test fail?

Tags: macros, tex-core, conditionals, expansion

This should be easy, but I don't understand why the test below fails... I expected *Hurrah!* to be printed when the `\currentchar` count reaches 90 (i.e. the character code of `Z`).

There must be some expansion problem somewhere, but I believe I use `\expandafter` as is necessary, here. What am I doing wrong? Should I take a different approach?

[image]

```
\def\mysteryletter{Z}

% loop through A-Z to find out the mystery letter
\newcount\currentchar
\currentchar=65 % <-- charcode of A
\loop
  \edef\temp{\char\currentchar}
  \temp
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\ifx\expandafter\mysteryletter\temp Hurrah!\fi
  \advance \currentchar by 1
  \unless\ifnum \currentchar>90
\repeat

\bye
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

add

```
> \show\temp
```

and you will see that the `\edef`  has made no difference, neither `\char` nor `\currentchar` are expandable, so `\temp` consists of those two tokens every time, and never is `\ifx` equal to a character token.

luatex has an expandable `\Uchar` primitive.

In this case it is easier to test the character code rather than the token.

```
\def\mysteryletter{Z}

% loop through A-Z to find out the mystery letter
\newcount\currentchar
\currentchar=65 % <-- charcode of A
\loop
  \char\currentchar
  \expandafter\ifnum\expandafter`\mysteryletter=\currentchar Hurrah!\fi
  \advance \currentchar by 1
  \unless\ifnum \currentchar>90
\repeat

\bye
```

Comment: Thanks David. Is there any way around using LuaTeX?

Comment: @Jubobs do you mean a way _using_ luatex or a way to avoid using luatex (the answer is yes either way)

Comment: I mean *a way to avoid using luatex*. And what would be *the way*? `:)`

Comment: @Jubobs updated

Comment: Great stuff! Thanks again. I'll remember to use `\show` next time...

Answer (score 13):

```
\chardef\mysteryletter=`Z
% loop through A-Z to find out the mystery letter
\newcount\currentchar

\currentchar=`A
\loop
  \chardef\temp=\the\currentchar
  \temp
  \ifx\mysteryletter\temp Hurrah!\fi
  \advance \currentchar by 1
  \unless\ifnum \currentchar>90
\repeat

\bye
```

Comment: Thanks, Herbert. I guess I should go back to the first few chapters of the TeXbook...