# Seemingly unused \edef prior to an \ifx mysteriously affects the outcome of the \ifx. Why?

Tags: macros, conditionals, expansion

It is my understanding that in `\ifx\x\y xx \else yy \fi`, `\ifx` does NOT expand its arguments. If you want `\ifx` to compare the *expanded* values of `\x` and `\y`, then we need to do the expansion ourselves *before* feeding them to `\ifx`:

```
\edef\xpndX{\x}
\edef\xpndY{\y}
\ifx\xpndX\xpndY xx \else yy \fi
```

as`\edef` does this expansion for us. This is frequently the case when `\x` and `\y` are the arguments in a macro so we really have no idea what kind of quantity they represent.

I was adapting a code snippet I found in user2478's answer to the TeX-SE question [Why does this simple \ifx test fail?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159793/why-does-this-simple-ifx-test-fail) and came up with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} % to get named colors

\begin{document}

\chardef\mysteryletter=`H
% loop through A-Z to find out the mystery letter
\newcount\currentchar

\currentchar=`A
\loop
  \chardef\temp=\the\currentchar
  \edef\tmp{\temp}%
  \ifx\mysteryletter\temp {\color{Red}\bf\temp}\else\temp\fi
  \advance \currentchar by 1
  \unless\ifnum \currentchar>90
\repeat

\end{document}
```

which, when compiled, generated the output:

[image]

which actually is the desired output, but it should *NOT* have been! I added the statement `\edef\tmp{\temp}` to get the 'expanded' version of `\temp` intending to change the `\temp` argument to the `\ifx` command to `\tmp` but had not when this document was compiled. Lo and behold, the desired result was printed out! This lead me to believe that the expansion performed by the `\edef\tmp{\temp}` statement was not required, so it was commented out and the document recompiled. This gave the wrong result; the letter H was not bold or red

[image]

I note that removing the comment character from the end of the `\edef` command had the expected affect of adding a space between each letter, but did not prevent the 'H' from being found and highlighted.

So my question is this: How does the unused expansion of `\temp` by the `\edef` statement change the comparison performed by the `\ifx` command? What am I missing here?

Comment: "Lo and behold", not "low and behold"

Comment: `\chardef\temp=\the\currentchar` should *always* be `\chardef\temp=\currentchar`. There's no point in using `\the` (besides the desire of seeing your code break loose).

Comment: @egreg: Very true, but such things are not always _bad_ things when it leads to new insight. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
  \chardef\temp=\the\currentchar
  \edef\tmp{\temp}%
```

tokens defined via `\chardef` are not expandable, so `\edef\tmp{\temp}` is the same as `\def\tmp{\temp}`

It is not clear why you do not expect `\ifx\mysteryletter\temp` not to be true if the two tokens are both defined via `\chardef` with the same number?

I guess your modified version was equivalent to

```
  \chardef\temp=\the\currentchar
  \ifx\mysteryletter\temp
```

There the `\ifx` test happens before the assignment while looking to end the number, you need

```
  \chardef\temp=\the\currentchar\relax
  \ifx\mysteryletter\temp
```

or

```
  \chardef\temp=\currentchar
  \ifx\mysteryletter\temp
```

So your `\edef` was just acting like `\relax` terminating the `\chardef` assignment.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. Still trying to figure out how to use the TeX-SE question and comment editors, please be patient. I had planned on converting this snippet into a `\def\scanAlpha#1{...` so I coded it the way I did expecting the macro argument to be used in the `\ifx` to be somewhat unknown at execution time, say be using `scanAlpha{X}` which would make the argument to the `\ifx` different from using the `\chardef` as in the snippet.

Comment: As stated, removing the `\edef` and using either `\chardef\temp=\the\currentchar\relax` or `\chardef\temp=\currentchar` works just fine. Aah, such are the mysteries of `\relax`ing. Not sure if I will ever figure out how to `\relax`. Thanks again for this answer.

Comment: @OneMugit'its not really the `\relax`  just that expansion happens when looking for a number, `\count0=1\ifx ab 2\else 3\fi ` sets count0 to 13 with the ifx test happening before the assignment, but  `\count0=1 \ifx ab 2\else 3\fi ` sets count0 to 1

Comment: Thanks for this illustration. I had not realized that a numeric assignment was so 'aggressive'. I take it that this expansion would continue even farther if that expansion kept producing more numbers, that is, continue until a non-number token was encountered, right? One other issue here, the assignment in your example generates a decimal number. Is it possible to generate numbers in other bases, hexadecimal for instance?

Comment: After some reflection about how `\ifx` expands its arguments, it seems that the statement I made in my question that `` `\ifx` does NOT expand its arguments'' is not strictly correct, as it must surely expand them at least once if that argument is a control sequence. Is that correct?

Comment: @OneMug it doesn't expand them (that is, it does not add the expansion to the input buffer) but it compares the first level s (that is the notion if equality being tested)

Comment: OK. I think I have it figured, that in my question, in the statement `\ifx\xpndX\xpndY xx \else yy \fi`, the control sequences `\xpndX' and `\xpndY` will each be expanded once, retrieving whatever result the respective `\edef` statements had ``saved'' there and uses those quantities in its comparison test without ever putting those (once expanded) results into the input stream, right?