# Listings - Keyword with Regex

Tags: listings, l3regex

I would like to colorize in a special color all my constant which are all in capital letters in my code and all my method variables which begin with an @.

Is it possible to use Regex to define keywords with listings package ?
It will help me for a lot of things !

For example, I actually have in a `\lstdefinestyle`:

```
keywords=[3]{@someName,@anotherName,@aboutOneHundredMore}
keywords=[4]{SOME_NAME,ANOTHER_NAME,ABOUT_ONE_HUNDRED_MORE}
```

--> If I could replace this by:

```
keywords=[3]{/@.+/}
keywords=[4]{/[A-Z_]+/}
```

it will save me from a lot of work !

If not, is there another way to have all my constant in a special color without defining all of them one by one in a keywords list ?

I first think about using `morecomment` or `moredelim` for the @ part but the ending character is problematic: it can be a space, a dot or a lot of other characters...

Comment: It would be *very* nice. Unfortunately it seems almost impossible to do it. Probably with a package based on Pygments like `minted` it would be possible, by defining a suitable lexer.

Comment: OK :'(
Is there at least a way to define more than one ending for a `morecomment` ?
For example: `morecomment=[s][\color{Red}]{@}{\ ,.,]}` or `morecomment=[s][\color{Red}]{@}{\ }{.}{]}`

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159246/can-the-listings-package-highlight-by-regexp