# listings: highlight part of a delimited word starting with space

Tags: listings

I would like to create a `lstlisting` language for a syntax that highlights namespaces for readability. Here's what I want to achieve:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.4,0.4,0.4}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.6}
\definecolor{cyan}{rgb}{0.0,0.6,0.6}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    columns=fullflexible,
    showstringspaces=false,
    commentstyle=\color{gray}\upshape
}

\lstdefinelanguage{turtle}
{
    stringstyle=\color{black},
    identifierstyle=\color{darkblue},
    keywordstyle=\color{cyan},
    moredelim=[is][\color{orange!80!black}]{!}{!},
    moredelim=[l][\color{orange!80!black}]{\ }{:} % my best guess: does not work
}

\begin{document}
\lstset{language=turtle}
\begin{lstlisting}
 !a!:b !c!:d !e!:f .
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image: desired output]

However, I would like to avoid having to put `!` explicitly in the input to wrap the namespaces. The command `moredelim=[l][\color{orange!80!black}]{\ }{:}` has no effect unless I put a space directly before and after each `:`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can insert color codes into the identifiers using a regular expression with `expl3` (see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/238832/89417) as follows:

1. include the prefix in the identifier tokens with `alsoletter{:}`
2. define a new command as `identifierstyle` to which the tokens are passed by `lstlisting`
3. expand the current token (using the `o` argument specifier)
4. add the color commands with a regex (using the syntax for building commands with `\c{}` and `\cB{`,`\cE}`) on the two matching groups `\1` and `\2`
5. print the replaced token
6. return a command to `identifierstyle` which will be applied to the current token by `lstlisting`, define this command such that nothing is printed.

Note that it would be cleaner to modify `c{lst@token}` in-place (instead of step 5 and 6), but due to my lack of knowledge about `expl3` I didn't do that :)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,xparse}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.6}
\colorlet{orangeb}{orange!80!black}
\def\noprint#1{}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \namespaces { }
{
    \tl_set:No \l_demo_tl {\the\use:c{lst@token}}
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { ([a-zA-Z]*):([a-zA-Z]*) } { \c{textcolor}\cB{ orangeb \cE}\cB{ \1 \cE}:\c{textcolor}\cB\{ darkblue \cE\}\cB{ \2 \cE} } \l_demo_tl
    \tl_use:N \l_demo_tl
    \noprint
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    alsoletter={:},
    columns=fullflexible,
    identifierstyle=\namespaces
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
a:b c:d e:f .
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks (and thanks for the explanation (and the introduction to exp3!)!).

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/650970/4427 for a fix with a more recent LaTeX