# Syntax highlighting of (Cisco) terminal

Tags: highlighting, syntax-highlighting, bash, lstlisting

I want to highlight a complete terminal flow, mostly for the Cisco CLI, but Bash would be nice, too. As for now, the result achieved with the package `lstlisting` looks as follows:

[image]

I achieved that with the following code:

```
\lstdefinestyle{default}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{background},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    breaklines=true,
    commentstyle=\color{comments},
    deletekeywords={},
    escapeinside={}{},
    extendedchars=true,
    frame=lines,
    keepspaces=true,
    keywordstyle=\color{keywords},
    morekeywords={},
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\color{numbers},
    rulecolor=\color{numbers},
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    stepnumber=1,
    stringstyle=\color{strings},
    tabsize=2,
    title=\filename{\lstname}
}

\lstset{
    style=default,
}

\lstdefinelanguage{cisco-terminal}{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize\color{keywords},
    morecomment=[l][\color{black}]{\#},
    morecomment=[l][\color{black}]{>},
    morecomment=[s][\color{strings}]{*}{'},
    morecomment=[s][\color{strings}]{`}{'},
    numbers=none
}
```

The problem I have, is that the output of certain commands (do sh run) can only be highlighted when I surround them with ` and '. If I do not, certain snippets may look like this:
[image]

Does anybody have an idea how to achieve the upper result in a better way (without the ` and ')? Are there any packages for this use case out there?

The test code can be found here: https://pastebin.com/ZSFb6ymi

A fully compileable example with and without workaround can be found here: https://pastebin.com/qRGfgkPj

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you please make your example a full compilable document? Ideally, one that includes a sample snippet of how the wrongly formatted code looks like and one that has your workarounds applied, so that we can see the differences between both. Perhaps switching to the [minted](https://ctan.org/pkg/minted) package is another option. There already seems to be a [lexer for Cisco console output](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/pull-requests/649/add-cisco-cli-lexer/diff)

Comment: Hello @siracusa. Here is the fully compileable document: https://pastebin.com/qRGfgkPj . Thank you for mentioning the minted package! I'll have a look at that, but I prefer lstlisting.

Comment: I don't think you can get the desired result by just using listings' standard facilities. Perhaps a regex-based solution like in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/439396/listings-highlight-a-prefixed-keyword-starting-with-a-single-quote) would work, but I'm not sure how to apply that here