# Using a regular expression within listings : Incomplete \iffalse

Tags: listings, expl3

I have used this pattern (found on this site) many times to animate listings in beamer. Unfortunately, it does not work anymore.

This code comes from a solution to this issue :
[listings: highlight part of a delimited word starting with space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402135/listings-highlight-part-of-a-delimited-word-start)

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,xparse}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.6}
\colorlet{orangeb}{orange!80!black}
\def\noprint#1{}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \namespaces { }
{
    \tl_set:No \l_demo_tl {\the\use:c{lst@token}}
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { ([a-zA-Z]*):([a-zA-Z]*) } { \c{textcolor}\cB{ orangeb \cE}\cB{ \1 \cE}:\c{textcolor}\cB\{ darkblue \cE\}\cB{ \2 \cE} } \l_demo_tl
    \tl_use:N \l_demo_tl
    \noprint
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    alsoletter={:},
    columns=fullflexible,
    identifierstyle=\namespaces
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
a:b c:d e:f .
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Here is the error message (same with pdflatex, latex, xelatex):

```
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test3.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-04-10>
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstmisc.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.cfg))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.def)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/dvips.def)) (./test3.aux))
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 30.
<inserted text>
                \fi
```

Do you have an idea to make this very useful code functional again ?

Comment: Side note, you could have debugged this by printing out `\l_demo_tl` with `\tl_analysis_show:N` (or if it's too verbose I recommend using my package)

Comment: @frougon It does? You'll see that the letters "orangeb" are active so would deduce that they would (do what active tokens do instead of typeset the letters themselves) when executed.

Answer (score 3):

The failure is due to the fact that recent implementations of the `l3regex` module use the current category code for characters when performing the replacement; inside `lstlisting` the current category code for the letters a-z is 13 (active), so the problem ensues. In the “search” part, `l3regex` is catcode agnostic (unless you specify a precise charcode,catcode pair).

The fix is simple: declare you want other characters (catcode 12) when doing the replacement: `\cO(orangeb)`, for instance. Also the colon should be declared “other”.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.6}
\colorlet{orangeb}{orange!80!black}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \namespaces { m }
  {
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {\the\use:c{lst@token}}
    \regex_replace_all:nnN
      { ([a-zA-Z]*):([a-zA-Z]*) } % any run of letters with a colon in between
      { 
        \c{textcolor}\cB\{ \cO(orangeb) \cE\}\cB\{ \1 \cE\} % first part orange
        \cO:
        \c{textcolor}\cB\{ \cO(darkblue) \cE\}\cB\{ \2 \cE\} % second part blue
      }
      \l_tmpa_tl
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    alsoletter={:},
    columns=fullflexible,
    identifierstyle=\namespaces
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
a:b c:d e:f .
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (alternatively use `\c.` to revert to the "old behavior" (any cat matches) I think.

Comment: @user202729 The problem here was the *output* of the regex replacement. `\cL(orangeb)` and `\cL(darkblue)` also work.

Comment: @user202729 No, the problem is in the ***replacement*** phase, not in the search phase.

Comment: (Maybe clarify like this. There are 2 overlapping usage of "letter" here.)

Comment: @user202729 Added some comments.